# Change buildstep color

Tags: python, buildbot

I want to change the buildstep color based on some warnings I get from my test. I have tried overriding some class methods to no success. What is the ideal way to change buildstep color based on the condition I provide?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no way to change the color dynamically using some variable or method.

The color is hardcoded in the CSS file which can be found in the `public_html` directory under the master directory on the build master.

If you look at the file `default.css` inside the `public_html`, which is used to render the web pages, you can find `BuildStep` states which defines the color and other properties.  I would say the colors are quite standard.

```
.success {
    color: #000;
    background-color: #8d4; --> corresponds to green
    border-color: #4F8530;
}

.failure {
    color: #000;
    background-color: #e88; --> corresponds to red
    border-color: #A77272;
}

.warnings {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #fa3; --> corresponds to orange
    border-color: #C29D46;
```

Maybe you can change the `default.css` with the color you want and then restart the build master. That's the only way I can see this happening. Hope it helps.